# What is wrong with this implementation of IDA* algorithm in Haskell? Bad heuristic or simply bad code?

Tags: algorithm, haskell, iterative-deepening

I am trying to write a haskell program which can solve rubiks' cube. Firstly I tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31583603/how-to-implement-the-thistlethwaites-algorithm-in-haskell), but did not figure a way out to avoid writing a whole lot of codes, so I tried using an IDA* search for this task.

But I do not know which heuristic is appropriate here: I tried dividing the problem into subproblems, and measuring the distance from being in a reduced state, but the result is disappointing: the program cannot reduce a cube that is three moves from a standard cube in a reasonable amount of time. I tried measuring parts of edges, and then either summing them, or using the maximums... but none of these works, and the result is almost identical.

So I want to know what the problem with the code is: is the heuristic I used non-admissible? Or is my code causing some infinite loops that I did not detect? Or both? And how to fix that? The code (the relevant parts) goes as follows:

```
--Some type declarations
data Colors = R | B | W | Y | G | O
type R3 = (Int, Int, Int)
type Cube = R3 -> Colors
points :: [R3] --list of coordinates of facelets of a cube; there are 48 of them.
mU :: Cube -> Cube --and other 5 similar moves.

type Actions = [Cube -> Cube]

turn :: Cube -> Actions -> Cube --chains the actions and turns the cube.

edges :: [R3] --The edges of cubes

totheu1 :: Cube -> Int  -- Measures how far away the cube is from having the cross of the first layer solved.
totheu1 c = sum $ map (\d -> if d then 0 else 1)
                      [c (-2, 3, 0) == c (0, 3, 0),
                       c (2, 3, 0) == c (0, 3, 0),
                       c (0, 3, -2) == c (0, 3, 0),
                       c (0, 3, 2) == c (0, 3, 0),
                       c (0, 2, -3) == c (0, 0, -3),
                       c (-3, 2, 0) == c (-3, 0, 0),
                       c (0, 2, 3) == c (0, 0, 3),
                       c (3, 2, 0) == c (3, 0, 0)]

expandnr :: (Cube -> Cube) -> Cube -> [(Cube, String)] -- Generates a list of tuples of cubes and strings, 

-- the result after applying a move, and the string represents that move, while avoiding moving on the same face as the last one, 

-- and avoiding repetitions caused by commuting moves, like U * D = D * U.

type StateSpace = (Int, [String], Cube) -- Int -> f value, [String] = actions applied so far, Cube = result cube.

fstst :: StateSpace -> Int
fstst s@(x, y, z) = x

stst :: StateSpace -> [String]
stst s@(x, y, z) = y

cbst :: StateSpace -> Cube
cbst s@(x, y, z) = z

stage1 :: Cube -> StateSpace
stage1 c = (\(x, y, z) -> (x, [sconcat y], z)) t
 where
 bound = totheu1 c
 t = looping c bound
 looping c bound = do let re = search (c, [""]) (\j -> j) 0 bound
                      let found = totheu1 $ cbst re
                      if found == 0 then re else looping c found
 sconcat [] = ""
 sconcat (x:xs) = x ++ (sconcat xs)

straction :: String -> Actions -- Converts strings to actions

search :: (Cube, [String]) -> (Cube -> Cube) -> Int -> Int -> StateSpace
search cs@(c, s) k g bound
 | f > bound = (f, s, c)
 | totheu1 c == 0 = (0, s, c)
 | otherwise = ms
 where
 f = g + totheu1 c
 olis = do
         (succs, st) <- expandnr k c
         let [newact] = straction st
         let t = search (succs, s ++ [st]) newact (g + 1) bound
         return t
 lis = map fstst olis
 mlis = minimum lis
 ms = olis !! (ind)
 Just ind = elemIndex mlis lis
```

I know that this heuristic is inconsistent, but am not sure if it is really admissible, maybe the problem is its non-admissibility?

Any ideas, hints, and suggestions are well appreciated, thanks in advance.

Comment: If it's three moves away from being solved, you should have no trouble solving it with IDA* even with a trivial heuristic - making no cuts and putting the expansions in any order. Getting rid of the heuristic and trying that would let you eliminate or identify the heuristic as a source of the problem.

Comment: @Cirdec I changed the heuristic to 0 if it is reduced, and 1 otherwise, but the program still outputs nothing... I think the code must be wrong somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

Your heuristic is inadmissible. An admissible heuristic must be a lower bound on the real cost of a solution.

You are trying to use as a heuristic the number of side pieces of the first layer that aren't correct, or perhaps the number of *faces* of the side pieces of the first layer that aren't correct, which is what you have actually written. Either way the heuristic is inadmissible.

The following cube is only `1` move away from being solved, but `4` of the pieces in the first layer are in incorrect positions and `4` of the faces have the wrong color. Either heuristic would say that this puzzle will take at least `4` moves to solve when it can be solved in only `1` move. The heuristics are inadmissible, because they are not lower bounds on the real cost of the solution.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. But changing the heuristic to 0 if reduced and 1 otherwise didn't help much: in this case the heuristic should be admissible, right? Maybe I should re-write the code again.

Comment: I'd encourage you to refactor the code so that IDA* search is written generically for any problem and successor Rubik's cube moves are independent of the heuristic. This will let you test each part separately from the others. IDA* search can be written in terms of a `heuristic :: Num cost => node -> cost` and a successors function `expand :: node -> [(cost, node)]` giving the whole function the type `idastar :: Num cost, Alternative f => (node -> cost) -> (node -> [(cost, node)]) -> node -> f node`.

Comment: I am not enough experienced in Haskell to understand your proposed function: What does it have to do with Alternative here? Why the result of idastar is in f node? Should I employ of something that both forms a Monoid and is an Applicative functor? And thanks for the suggestion to separate the heuristic and expand out! Lastly, may I ask is there any problem with the stage1 I wrote? Namely, does it cause any obvious infinite loops? Or is that code too chaotic to understand properly?

Comment: @awllower You can just use `Maybe` for "there might be a result" instead of any `Alternative f => f`. It might still be useful to use `<|>` from `Alternative` since the monoid instance for `Maybe` is useless. The `Applicative`/`Alternative` instance for `Maybe` is just `pure = Just`, `<*>` and `liftA2` combine `Just`s, `empty = Nothing`, and `<|>` takes the first `Just`. Using `Alternative` you could substitute a list and get all the answers in order as well.

Comment: You mean when it is not possible to reduce the cube then the result would be a Nothing? OK, I shall try to work out in this direction. Thanks again!